# Why do I receive a warning for1I64<<31?

Tags: c++, c

Why do I receive a warning for this code ?

```
switch(iInput)
{
   ...
   case 1I64<<31:   return 31;  break;
   ...
}
```

1>C:\path-to-file.cpp(44) : warning C4309: 'case' : truncation of constant value

1I64<<31 is 0x0000000080000000  (__int64) so no truncation here, 
it's there a maximum value for case ?

Comment: Dupe comment deleted :) Yeah, I'm betting the type of 'case' isn't 64 bits wide.

Comment: In `C` (don't know about `C++`) it is a syntax error to have `"case"` as an identifier inside the `switch` expression. Also `1I64` has no defined meaning ... and triggers another syntax error

Comment: The `I64` suffix on the literal is new to me.  Is that a compiler-specific suffix, or part of a standard I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @Max Lybbert The `I64` part is Microsoft-specific; all other compilers use `ll` instead; a portable one would be `INT64_C(1)`.

Comment: @anatolyg: sadly, MSVC only has the `INT64_C` (from `stdint.h`) starting with MSVC 10.  At least they do finally have it  (and there are plenty of available `stdint.h` files for earlier versions of MSVC floating on the net - as a matter of fact, it seems like MSVC 10's might work in earlier versions of MSVC).

Comment: @ernest, john, pmg: was a typo in the post. I have modified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the expression controlling the `switch` controls they type of the expression the `case` labels will use.

You'll need an `__int64` (or equivalent) type in the controlling expression to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 3):

The C Standard ([n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) states

> 6.8.4.2/5 The integer promotions are performed on the controlling expression. ...

and

> 6.3.1.1/2 ... the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int ...

My guess is that `int` (or `unsigned int`) in your implementation is not large enough to hold 64-bit-wide values.